# Need to delete all bower components and do fresh bower install on every checkout

Tags: angularjs, git, bower, git-checkout, bower-install

Every time I checkout a new branch, then switch back to the branch I was working on, I run into a long list of missing module errors in my JS console. The missing modules are all bower components. If I delete my bower_components folder, then do a fresh bower install, everything works again. Why do I have to do this every time I checkout the branch? Thanks.

Comment: are you using grunt or gulp? can you provide some code?

Comment: yeah, using grunt. what code would be most helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git hooks to accomplish this. Check out [digital ocean's article on them](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) for a list.

Specifically, I think `post-merge` and `post-checkout` are the ones you are interested in.

Git hooks are just simple shell scripts. Place the following into `.git/hooks/post-merge` and `.git/hooks/post-checkout`:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf bower_components/
bower install
```

Then make sure that the files are executable by running the following:

```
chmod 755 .git/hooks/post-checkout
chmod 755 .git/hooks/post-merge
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the issue I'm running into a standard occurrence when using bower?

Comment: It's likely not every checkout that it needs to be done, just when someone is changing a dependency in your bower.json file, in which case yes, you need to install them every time they change.

Comment: Thanks, I think there must be an issue with my setup then. Even if no changes have been made, and I return to the branch after just a few seconds, I'll need to erase the bower folder and run an entire bower install again.